# A tool to browse my rails app's database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord

I want a way to comprehensively view:

```
1. what's going on in my database
2. what the schema looks like
```

Is there a good tool that lets you do that?

Comment: Sorry, but [we don't really do tool requests here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/125392/133242). Try Google.

Comment: @MattBall First of all, I'm not "Shopping". Take a look at the article you yourself linked to in your answer http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/ I'm not buying a macbook or any software. I still do not think there's anything wrong with asking question like this. Second, I looked all over Google and saw some of the premature tools out there but couldn't figure out what is the most frequently used tool. Isn't that the point of asking questions here?

Comment: It's irrelevant that you're not looking to pay for it. The last paragraph of the answer: _"But Stack Overflow is not a 'tool-finding' service. I'm not sure how well asking questions with no current solution scales... I'm inclined to think such questions are too localized."_

Comment: Urgh I hate the pernickety, nerdy side of Stack Overflow. Vlad has a problem, we have the answer, end of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a gem Active Admin that lets you do that: http://activeadmin.info/documentation.html

And of course you can use any other Administration tool that lets you connect to your database, for instance Squirrel http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/ which connects to various sql databases, sqlite among them.

For development and testing, I would say the preferred way of knowing your data is generating it automatically using tools like FactoryGirl or Faker and look into schema.rb for the schema.